# ajax just work first time for page load

Tags: ajax, jquery

this thing is killing me for two days
i have this simple code:

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['headerload'])){?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://royta.ir/js/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://royta.ir/js/main.js'?>"></script>
<div id="content">
<? } ?>

<a class="item ajax"  base="basic" data-title="تنظیمات عمومی" href="http://royta.ir/general/" data-url="/general/" title="تنظیمات عمومی" >asdasd</a>
```

and this jquery

```
$(function() {
$('a.ajax').click(function(eee){
    eee.preventDefault();
    var location = $(this).attr('href') + '&headerload';
    var base = $(this).attr('base');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var titlepage = $(this).attr('data-title');
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    $('#content').html('');
    $('#content').empty();
    //change title


        $.ajax({url:location,success:function(loaddataa){
            document.title = titlepage;
            window.history.pushState(null, titlepage, url);

            $('#content').html(loaddataa);
        }
        });

});
```

})
but when i run this page http://royta.ir/general as you can see
its just run 1 time with ajax and everything fine but if you click again on link page will reloaded
anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your click handler is assigned before your content is added to the page. You need to use a delegate.

```
$("body").on("click", "a.ajax", function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Ideally, you would replace `body` with a parent selector as close to `a.ajax` as possible. But `body` is sure to work.

```
<div id="foo">
    <!-- a.ajax inserted here -->
</div>

$("#foo").on("click", "a.ajax", function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Here's jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8jqX9/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: work like charm ! after load main.js in end of file ! thank you

Answer (score 5):

You see... when you run `$('#content').html(loaddataa);`, a new `<a />` is loaded onto the page, so the event (`$('a.ajax').click`) that you bound to the element isn't there anymore.

If you really want your page to keep working like it is a valid HTML page, then try replacing

```
$('a.ajax').click(function(eee){
```

with

```
$('a.ajax').on('click', function(eee){
```

which binds to elements created in the future.

Comment: hmm i dont another <a /> in page with firefox page source ... let me test it.

Comment: i use $('a.ajax').on('click',function(eee){ now but same problem